# How to unpack std::tuple from C++ template?

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++17

I have a class that is expected to take `std::tuple` of certain types (arbitrary count is allowed) as a template argument. I want to declare a tuple of vectors of the types. For instance, I have

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {/*...*/}
```

I instantiate it

```
MyClass<std::tuple<int, bool>> my_class;
```

and I aim to create a field like this

```
std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<bool>> my_tuple;
```

I know that if I had a class definition

```
template <typename... T>
class MyClass2 {/*...*/}
```

I could instantiate it by passing the data types without a tuple

```
MyClass<int, bool> my_class2;
```

and then simply create the field

```
std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<bool>> my_tuple2;
```

using

```
std::tuple<std::vector<T>...> my_tuple2;
```

Hence, I was thinking that I should somehow unpack the data types from the tuple. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and to add to cigien's answer, another way to go about it would be to unpack it through a template specialization.

```
template<typename Tuple>
class MyClass;

template<typename... Ts>
class MyClass<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    // ...
    using VectorTuple = std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>;
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Nice. This is an elegant solution. +1

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you just need another level of indirection (as usual):

```
// this function declaration is used just for the type
// transformation, and needs no definition
template <typename... Types>
auto unpack(std::tuple<Types...>) -> std::tuple<std::vector<Types>...> ;

template <typename Tuple>
class MyClass
{
  // use the return type of unpack
  decltype(unpack(std::declval<Tuple>())) my_tuple; 
};
```

And now you can instantiate `MyClass` with a `tuple`, like this:

```
MyClass<std::tuple<int, double>> m;
```

which contains a field `my_tuple` of type

```
std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>>
```

Here's a working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9PPFfp).

Comment: I am going to accept Travis's answer, since I found it slightly more elegant. However, thank you very much too.